# AKS new nodepool provisioning with terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-aks

I already have an AKS cluster but want to add a new nodepool by using terraform, but I couldn't find `kubernetes_cluster_id` value. So I'm wondering if it's possible to create a new nodepool in existing AKS cluster with terraform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a data source to extract the cluster-ID and then just reference it in the `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool` resource where the `kubernetes_cluster_id` is required.

```
data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
  name                = "myakscluster"
  resource_group_name = "my-example-resource-group"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "example" {
  name                  = "internal"
  kubernetes_cluster_id = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.id
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS2_v2"
  node_count            = 1

  tags = {
    Environment = "Production"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to add a new node pool to an existing AKS Cluster with Terraform?

**Answer:** Yes, You can use the `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool` resource in Terraform to create a new node pool and use the resource ID of the existing AKS Cluster as a reference for `kubernetes_cluster_id`.

---

You can find your `kubernetes_cluster_id` in the Azure Portal or Azure CLI.

### Azure CLI

**Command:**

```bash
az aks show --resource-group <your-resource-group> --name <your-aks-cluster-name> --query id -o tsv
```

**Output:**

```bash
/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/my-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/my-aks-cluster
```

### Azure Portal

[image: Find kubernetes_cluster_id on Azure Portal]

Comment: You should explain how to query the ID since this is running in Terraform, its best practice to not hard code the ID.